# PG_SEARCH gem search specific columns only for JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, pg-search

I have jsonb column in my postgres table and i want to search only one key not all the keys.

e.g.

```
Book.create!(details: {authour: 'example', title: 'something'} 

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search,
                  against: [
                    :details
                  ]
end
```

I want to search titles and ignore the author names.

Answer (score 3):

There is a request for this on their GitHub page, however it [is not supported](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/issues/252) at the moment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23163478)

Comment: @AniketG I disagree. "This isn't possible" is, in fact, an answer. I don't know if it's the *correct* answer or not, but that should be settled by voting rather than by the VLQ queue.

Comment: @AniketG It's more useful to see a link to an appropriate resource for "This isn't possible" than seeing that no one has answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by `pg_search_scope :search_for, against: :details, using: { tsearch: { any_word: true } }`.